# Getting the correct client height of an external SVG when it loads in Chrome

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm wanting to tie the height of a button to the height of an external SVG after it's been resized by a browser.

Jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2y8c69LL/4/).

Here's the script:

```
function svgLoad() {
    "use strict";

    this.wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    this.navID = document.querySelector('#slideMenu');
    this.menuButton = document.querySelector('#menuButton');
    this.logo = document.getElementById('logo');
    this.logoWrap = document.getElementById('logoWrap');
    this.navBar = document.getElementById('navBarWrap');

    console.log(this.logo);
    console.log(this.logo.clientHeight);
    console.log(this.navBar.clientHeight);

    this.loaded = function() {
        this.logoHeight = Math.round(this.logo.clientHeight);
        this.rect = this.logo.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(this.rect.height);
        console.log(this.logoHeight);
        console.log(this.navBar.clientHeight);
        // Sets height of menu button to match height of logo.
        this.menuButton.style.height = this.logoHeight + 'px';
        console.log(this.menuButton.style.height);
        this.wrapper.style.marginTop = this.navBar.clientHeight + 'px';
    }.bind(this);

    this.logo.onload = this.loaded;
} 

new svgLoad();
```

If I use window.onload everything displays fine, but I'd prefer the script to run once the SVG is ready. If I try running when the SVG object is loaded, I get different results across browsers.

Everything works fine in FF and Edge/IE using onload/addEventListener on the SVG.

In Chrome it it won't work at all, it consistently reports the SVG's size as 160px. It's showing the SVG as an anonymous function in the console, and within that the client height is calculated correctly; It just won't apply it to the script (possibly worth noting it reports the same height in the fiddle even though it doesn't load the SVG at all in Chrome).

**Edit** - having looked into this a bit more, Chrome seems to be changing the SVG's offsetTop property to make up the difference between the height it should dsisplay at and 160px.

Comment: You have error in your code it should be ` this.logo.onload = this.loaded;`

Comment: Indeed I do, thanks for pointing it out. That explains why onload wasn't working in FF and IE, but it doesn't explain why nothing works in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've playing with this and found an answer.

FF and IE/Edge will resize the SVG properly without either width or height specified on the object. Chrome requires that a height is specified before it sends the correct client height to the script.

For my purposes using rem/em was the best solution.